# Find the product of all quadratic nonresidues in $\mathbb{Z}_{103}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find the product of all quadratic nonresidues in $\mathbb{Z}_{103}$.

I would like to write down here my attempt, but know how to start. In our lectures note this problem appears just right after the definition of quadratic residue modulo $n$.

Since $103$ is a prime number, there are $\frac{103-1}{2} = 61$ quadratic nonresidues. I don't think I have to find each of them and the multiply each other.

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Hints: In a multiplicative group, is the inverse of a square also a square? To what extent can you pair up the nonzero residues?

Comment: Another version of the same hint: Can the inverse of a quadratic nonresidue be a quadratic residue? And: 61 is odd. So how this all add up (multiply out)?

Comment: Have you come across *primitive roots*? If so, can you express quadratic residues in terms of primitive roots?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown As fas as I understand, if $a$ is a primitive root $\mathrm{mod}$ $103$, then all odd powers of $a$ are quadratic nonresidues. So does it suffice to find that $a$, take its odd powers and then multiply those numbers together? Do I have to find $61$ such a numbers ‘’analytically’’?

Comment: I think I'm not gettting the hints ):

Answer (score 0):

Recall [Wilson's theorem for finite Abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization):

> The product of all elements in a finite Abelian group is either $1$ or the element of order $2$ if there is only one such element.

$\mathbb{Z}_{103}^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $102$. It has exactly one  element of order $2$, namely $-1$, and so the product of all its elements is $-1$.

The set of quadratic residues is a subgroup of order $61$. It has no element of order $2$ and so the product of all its elements is $1$.

Therefore, the product of all quadratic nonresidues is $-1 \bmod 103$.